# How to use url and amin-ajax.php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to redirect users back to a main page with a success message after the submit button with php and ajax. However, the users are sent to a blank page with the message. I believe it has to do with the location of admin-ajax.php

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax
            ({
                //data type that is being thrown around
                dataType: "json",
                // whether or not data is being posted or not
                type: "post",
                // serializing creates a URL encoded text string
                data: jQuery("#myForm").serialize(),
                // this is the location in which the url takes the data
                url: "../admin-ajax.php",
                success:function(data) 
                {
                
                    jQuery(".messageDiv").html(data.message);
                    
                    if(data.status == 1)
                    {
                        jQuery("#myForm").trigger('reset');
                    }
                },

            });
```

Is "../admin-ajax.php" the correct url? How does one interact with other pages without using the header() function in php?

Comment: Have you looked at using the modern REST API at `/wp-json` instead of the old Admin AJAX interface at `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`? Also avoid at all costs using relative urls such as `../admin-ajax.php` and use absolute URLs instead

Comment: Thank you so much for that helpful information! It's difficult finding videos on modern wordpress $wpdb and ajax integrations. Do you have any modern examples or helpful links?

Comment: a lot of it is covered on https://developer.wordpress.org/ but I would be suspicious of videos, there's a lot of video material on youtube that makes very questionable recommendations. Try to avoid raw SQL/`$wpdb`, it makes sense if you have to integrate with a different CMS, but otherwise custom taxonomies, custom post types, and post meta should be cover 99% of your needs. Using SQL to query WP tables also bypasses plugin filters, WP caches, etc, so it'll be slower to fetch data